# Show that $d\mathbf{v}^2/dt = 2\mathbf{v}\cdot d\mathbf{v}/dt$ using geometry only

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, differentiation, calculus, geometry

I have just begun reading *Modern Classical Physics* by Thorne and Blandford and I am trying to wrap my head around their "geometric viewpoint" on classical mechanics. The first exercise in the book is to show that a charged particle in an electromagnetic field has kinetic energy ($E$) that changes like
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}E}{\mathrm{d}t} = q(\mathbf{v}\cdot\mathbf{E})$$
*without any reference to coordinates.*

Now, starting from the Lorentz force law, I can show geometrically that the magnetic component falls out when taking the dot product of $\mathbf{v}$,
$$\mathbf{v}\cdot\left(m\,\frac{\mathrm{d}\mathbf{v}}{\mathrm{d}t}\right)=\mathbf{v}\cdot(q(\mathbf{E} + \mathbf{v}\times\mathbf{B})) = q(\mathbf{v}\cdot\mathbf{E})$$
since $\mathbf{v}$ is, by definition perpendicular to $\mathbf{v}\times\mathbf{B}$. Then, from here we use that
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}E}{\mathrm{d}t} = \frac{1}{2}m\, \frac{\mathrm{d}(\mathbf{v}^2)}{\mathrm{d}t}.$$
What I am stuck on is showing geometrically that $\mathrm{d}\mathbf{v}^2/\mathrm{d}t = 2\mathbf{v}\cdot \mathrm{d}\mathbf{v}/\mathrm{d}t$. Essentially, I am looking for some geometric intuition of the chain rule for vectors which will be applicable to more general problems in applying calculus concepts to geometry.

Comment: $v^2=\mathbf v\cdot\mathbf v$. Product rule no good?

Comment: I would advise people closing this question to have a look at Thorne and Blandford's book. Maybe they will understand the conceptual content of this question.

Comment: Why do you want restrict yourself to geometric interpretation? Wouldn't any interpretation work (e.g., simple calculus approach)

Comment: @KyleKanos From what I have read of the book so far, the point is that it is always possible to formulate (at least classical) physics in a geometric way and some problems that may be difficult analytically are much simpler to tackle geometrically. So it is useful to be comfortable with both approaches.

Comment: Do they define "geometrically", I think it has some different meaning based on context. I'd take it to mean "without regards to coordinates" but some of the answers seem to require orthonormal coordinate systems and rely on Euclidean forms (which could also be described as "geometric").

Comment: Yes, Thorne and Blanford say "geometrically" to mean "without reference to coordinates". Everything in the first part of the book (which is where the above exercise is from) is in flat spacetime so all of the non-relativistic physics can be treated using Euclidean geometry. They deal with curved spacetime and non-Euclidean geometry in the later sections.

Comment: The textbook is available on line as part of the [Applications of Classical Physics course at Caltech](http://www.pmaweb.caltech.edu/Courses/ph136/yr2011/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have another method that I think sticks to the geometric viewpoint of MCP.

Consider the velocity vector $\mathbf{v}$ of the particle. We'll look at how $v^2=\mathbf{v}\mathbf{\cdot}\mathbf{v}$ changes in over a small time $\Delta t$, and then take the limit $\Delta t \to 0$. The particle experiences an acceleration $\mathbf{\dot{v}}\equiv d\mathbf{v}/dt$ in the direction of the force $\mathbf{F}$ ($= q\mathbf{E}$ in this case). This gives us a natural, coordinate-free decomposition of the velocity vector into components parallel and perpendicular to the force, which allows us to write
$$
v^2 = v^2_\| + v^2_\perp.
$$

In a small time $\Delta t$, the velocity vector changes to $\mathbf{v}' = \mathbf{v} + \mathbf{\dot{v}}\Delta t$. The acceleration only changes the parallel component of the velocity by an amount $\Delta v_\| = |\mathbf{\dot{v}}|\Delta t$, whereas the perpendicular component is left unchanged:
$$
v'_\| = v_\| + |\mathbf{\dot{v}}|\Delta t, \ v'_\perp = v_\perp.
$$
The magnitude of the velocity vector is now
\begin{align}
v'^2 &= v'^2_\| + v'^2_\perp \\
     &= v^2_\| + v^2_\perp + 2v_\| |\mathbf{\dot{v}}|\Delta t + \left(|\mathbf{\dot{v}}|\Delta t\right)^2.
\end{align}
This then implies that $\Delta(v^2) = v'^2 - v^2 = 2v_\| |\mathbf{\dot{v}}|\Delta t + \left(|\mathbf{\dot{v}}|\Delta t\right)^2,$ which means
\begin{align}
\frac{d(v^2)}{dt} = \lim_{\Delta t \to 0} \frac{\Delta(v^2)}{\Delta t} = 2v_\| |\mathbf{\dot{v}}| = 2\mathbf{v}\mathbf{\cdot}\frac{d\mathbf{v}}{dt}.
\end{align}

Comment: I think this is the main point they are trying to make with the exercise: The use of breaking a vector into a parallel and a perpendicular component. It's clearly much more elegant to do this decomposition without reference to any underlying coordinates. This also seems to be the common theme of all of the answers here. Thank you, this is quite helpful.

Answer (score 5):

Your diagram was correct and I have added to it.

[image]

It shows the speed changing from $v$ at time $t$ to $v'$ at time $t+\delta t$ with the speed changing by $\delta v$.

The equivalent velocity diagram $\vec v' = \vec v + \delta \vec v$ is shown in the diagram.

$v'^2 = (v+\delta v \cos \theta)^2 +(\delta v\,\sin \theta )^2 \Rightarrow v'^2-v^2 = 2\,v\,\delta v \,cos \theta + (\delta v)^2$.

Let $\theta \to 0$ and you get the result you asked for.

---

Another approach is to use the cosine rule,  $v'^2 = v^2+(\delta v)^2 + 2\,v\,\delta v \,\cos \theta$ .

Comment: Pretty! Take my upvote.

Comment: Nice. But this proof goes in the opposite direction of  Thorne and Blandford's approach since it hinges on writing $\delta \vec v$ in the basis of $\vec v$ and its normal.

Comment: @GiorgioP-DoomsdayClockIsAt-90 I have added using the cosine rule.

Comment: I don't think this is the "geometric" meaning Thorne & Blandford intended. I imagine they mean geometric in the coordinate-free sense, rather than in the Euclidean sense. But I could be wrong, not having read the book ever.

Comment: @KyleKanos I too have not read the book so have had to make a guess as to what was wanted.  My derivation is really differentiation from first principles.

Answer (score 3):

In general, it is possible to show that for any pair of vectors ${\bf u}(t)$ and ${\bf v}(t)$,
$$
\frac{{\mathrm d}}{{\mathrm d}t} \left( {\bf u}(t)\cdot {\bf v}(t) \right)=
{\bf u}(t)\cdot\frac{{\mathrm d}}{{\mathrm d}t} {\bf v}(t) + {\bf v}(t)\cdot\frac{{\mathrm d}}{{\mathrm d}t} {\bf u}(t).
$$
This can be done in a coordinate-free form, as for the usual Leibnitz rule for the derivative of a product of two functions, by using the definition of the scalar product as a bi-linear functional in $V^2$ ($V$ being the vector space the two vectors belong to) and the definition of derivative es the limit of a finite difference formula.

Explicitly,
$$
\frac{{\mathrm d}}{{\mathrm d}t} \left( {\bf u}(t)\cdot {\bf v}(t) \right)=\lim_{\Delta t \rightarrow 0} \frac{{\bf u}(t+\Delta t)\cdot {\bf v}(t+\Delta t) -{\bf u}(t)\cdot {\bf v}(t)  }{\Delta t} \\ =
\lim_{\Delta t \rightarrow 0} \frac{{\bf u}(t+\Delta t)\cdot {\bf v}(t+\Delta t) -{\bf u}(t)\cdot {\bf v}(t+\Delta t)  }{\Delta t} + \lim_{\Delta t \rightarrow 0} \frac{{\bf u}(t)\cdot {\bf v}(t+\Delta t) -{\bf u}(t)\cdot {\bf v}(t)  }{\Delta t}\\
= {\bf v}(t)\cdot\frac{{\mathrm d}}{{\mathrm d}t} {\bf u}(t) +{\bf u}(t)\cdot\frac{{\mathrm d}}{{\mathrm d}t} {\bf v}(t).
$$

The trivial identity ${\bf v}(t)\cdot {\bf v}(t) = v^2(t)$ completes the proof. No reference to components of the vector in any basis has been introduced, and that's the core of Thorne and Blandford's approach. Moreover, it does not require additional definitions of the dot product with respect to Thorne and Blandford's  definition.

Comment: He specifically said that he is looking for geometrical proofs, not algebraic ones.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent I focused on the "without any reference to coordinates" requirement that I think is the Thorne and Blandford's point of view. The meaning of geometric is not unique, at least in the last century of math. By the way, derivatives are not purely geometric things, at least in the classical sense.

Comment: Yeah, I caught that too. I would have also used an algebraic method but it would be interesting to see a good geometrical proof anyway.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get this to work by a picture, you ought to have to work with the standard pictorial binomial proof of $(a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2$ with tiny $b$ to a big $a,$ so that the tiny $b^2$ can be neglected to first order.

It will be very clear that this will be a very rough proof. Visually, if $\mathrm d\vec v$ even has a big enough size to see, then even if it is perpendicular to $\vec v,$ it would look wrong to say that the area does not increase, because we would perceive the Pythagorean theorem.

Instead, $\mathrm d\vec v$ actually lives in a different mathematical space than $\vec v$ and really is not strictly meant to be drawn on the same picture, even though that is how we obviously want the calculus to work. To mean. But if we are strict in this sense, then the geometrical proofs will likely all not work, so we are stuck between a rock and a hard place.

The pictorial proof of the binomial expansion gives the correct visual intuition, though. It is very easy to see that the growth of the square is most related to the two line-looking rectangles that the growth of the square would naturally conjure up.

Comment: This is as rigorous as I am after. As I am self-studying I cannot be sure whether this is the "intended" answer. But this method is convincing enough to me.